# SQL where condition always true

Tags: sql

How to set in SQL a where condition that is always true?

As far as I know: `where 1=1`, are there other ways too?

Comment: You seem to have answered you own first question. The second part is not clear - is there any way to do what?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve, but being unsuccessful?  As @Oded says, you seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: where 2=2, where 3=3.. I can think of a few more as well...

Comment: what exactly you want ? where 2=2 :P

Comment: I needed this in some debug code so I could quickly hack in an extra filter if required..  Like '%%'

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Are you, by chance, talking about `collapse` conditions, where a grouped condition is always `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

```
WHERE TRUE
WHERE 1
WHERE <string value> = <the same string value>
WHERE <numeric value> = <the same numeric value>
WHERE <hardcoded formula> = <the same hardcoded formula or one that produces the same value>
WHERE NULL IS NULL
```

Comment: With MS SQL Server, `TRUE` and `1` don't seem to work.